# Unable to view the pyspark job in Spline using ec2 instance

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2, spline-data-lineage-tracker

We created a sample pyspark job and gave the spark-submit commands as following in ec2 instance

sudo ./bin/spark-submit --packages za.co.absa.spline.agent.spark:spark-3.1-spline-agent-bundle_2.12:0.6.1 --conf “spark.sql.queryExecutionListeners=za.co.absa.spline.harvester.listener.SplineQueryExecutionListener” --conf "spark.spline.lineageDispatcher.http.producer.url=http://[ec2]
(http://localhost:8080/producer)[:8080/producer](http://localhost:9090/producer)" --conf "spark.spline.lineageDispatcher=logging" /home/ec2-user/spline-sandbox/mysparkjob.py

we are able to view the output in the console but unable to view in spline UI what additional steps need to be done ?

Through docker how can we embed the pyspark job on an ec2 instance ?

Answer (score 0):

You set `spark.spline.lineageDispatcher=logging` that means instead of sending the lineage to spline server it is just written into the log. If you leave that out or set `spark.spline.lineageDispatcher=http` (which is the default) the lineage data should be send to `spark.spline.lineageDispatcher.http.producer.url`

I would also recommend using the latest version of spline currently 0.7.12.

You can see documentation of dispatchers and other Spline Agent features here:
https://github.com/AbsaOSS/spline-spark-agent/tree/develop
if using older version change the branch/tag to see older version of the docuemntation.